# What do I need to utilize Component how props?

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx, tsx

I have array of object

```
const userProfileRoutes = [
 {
  id: 0,
  path: "userInfo",
  name: "My profile",
  icon: CgProfile, // from react-icons
 },
 {
  id: 1,
  path: "adminPanel",
  name: "Admin panel",
  icon: MdAdminPanelSettings, // from react-icons
 },
 { id: 2, path: "editPanel", name: "Edit profile", icon: AiTwotoneSetting // from react-icons },
 { id: 3, path: "cart", name: "Cart", icon: AiOutlineShoppingCart // from react-icons },
];
```

and I use this array here

```
 {userProfileRoutes.map(({ id, path, name, icon }) => (
      <>
        // here I'd like to use icon props
        <MenuItem key={id} link={path}>
          {name}
        </MenuItem>
      </>
    ))}
```

I'd like to use icon props how component because it's component
What do I need for this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to capitalize the first letter of the icon name. This can be done during destructuring:

```js
{userProfileRoutes.map(({ id, path, name, icon: Icon }) => (
  <>
    <Icon />
    <MenuItem key={id} link={path}>
      {name}
    </MenuItem>
  </>
))}
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized

Comment: what about if a name of property will be Icon and  in props I will have userProfileRoutes.map(({ id, path, name, Icon }), What Difference Does It Make?

Comment: Yeah there isn’t much different in that way: naming objet keys `Icon` and then destructuring directly into `Icon` will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    userProfileRoutes.map(({ id, path, name, icon }) => (
        <>
            <icon />
            <MenuItem key={id} link={path}>
                {name}
            </MenuItem>
        </>
    ));
}
```

Comment: `<icon />` won’t work because components must have capitalized first letter in name.

Comment: Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.